How can I add user secrets as a configuration source in TokenAcquirerFactory?
I'm trying to add user secrets as a configuration source to TokenAcquirerFactory
My current best approach has been to create a class that inherets from TokenAcquirerFactory and then overrides the DefineConfiguration method which seems purpose built for my requirements;
internal class ConfigurableTokenAcquisitionFactory : TokenAcquirerFactory
{
    protected override string DefineConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
    
        var callingAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder.AddUserSecrets(callingAssembly);
        return base.DefineConfiguration(builder);
    }
}

I then create my ConfigurableTokenAcquisitionFactory instance like this;
var tokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<ConfigurableTokenAcquisitionFactory>(configurationSectionName);

This is partially successful. Provided I don't include the setting within appsettings.json I get the outcome I want however if the setting is duplicated in appsettings.json then this always takes precedence. My understanding of how settings are resolved is that secrets.json values should override appsettings.json values. Have I misunderstood something?
This is the base implementation of DefineConfiguration
    protected virtual string DefineConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly!.Location)!;
    }

This is how it is called within the base class
    private IConfiguration ReadConfiguration()
    {
        if (Configuration == null)
        {
            // Read the configuration from a file and augment/replace from environment variable
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            string basePath = DefineConfiguration(builder);
            builder.SetBasePath(basePath)
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        return Configuration;
    }

Ideally I would like to understand why this is happening, but ultimately I want a safe way of inserting settings from secrets.json and have them take precedence over any value in any other settings source.
How can I do this?
